# Call gravatar_for in Rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gravatar

I am trying to call gravatar_for from one of my models. (Yes I realise this isn't strictly MVC, but I have a legitimate reason for doing it which I am not going into). I'm trying to include the helpers for Gravatar but I haven't been successful in finding what they are.

So far including it inside my class like so doesn't work:

```
class AnnotationPostedActivity < NewsfeedActivity
  include GravatarHelper::PublicMethods
```

Comment: what gravatar gem are you using?

Comment: That's a good point, looks like Rails tutorial provides it's own implementation which I was using. I had only just realised after your comment, so thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using the [gravatar-plugin](https://github.com/woods/gravatar-plugin/) to generate image tags, there are a few problems to overcome.  Note that the `gravatar_for` method takes a user object as its first argument.

Mixing in `GravatarHelper::PublicMethods` to your `AnnotationPostedActivity` class gives all instances access to the method `gravatar_for(user, options={})`.  So you would say:

```
alice = User.new()

alice.respond_to?(:gravatar_for)
=> true

alice.gravatar_for
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
# (you need to supply an argument - the method got zero but was expecting one)

alice.gravatar_for(alice)
=> "<img class=\"gravatar\" alt=\"\" width=\"50\" height=\"50\" src=\"http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/70375a32ad79987b9bc00cb20f7d1c95?rating=PG&amp;size=50\" />
 # (not what we want at all)
```

You see, you must supply the `user` object as the first argument of the `gravatar_for` method.  So what you will have to do is

### 1. Use another gem

One that provides a module that looks at `self.email` instead of requiring it as a method parameter.

### 2. Implement the method yourself

[It's easy](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/hash/).  And there's [already ruby code](https://github.com/woods/gravatar-plugin/blob/master/lib/gravatar.rb#L67-81) to follow.  You *will probably need* to include some of Rails' helpers in your `AnnotationPostedActivity` model

```
>> gravatar_url 'github@deanandadie.net`
NoMethodError: undefined method `h' for main:Object ....

>> require 'active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety'
=> true

>> include ERB::Util
=> Object

>> gravatar_url 'github@deanandadie.net`
=> "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/fbaf55d6c2618cafe0a759cfe85967e0?rating=PG&size=50"
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a helper module you're trying to mix into your Model, then this is a signal that things need to be moved around a bit. Helpers are really view helpers, and should only be called from the view. If there's logic there that is also useful in the model itself, then move it to a lib. For example:

```
# lib/gravatar_utils.rb
module GravatarUtils
  def gravatar_for(user)
    # ...
  end
end

# app/helpers/gravatar_helper.rb
class GravatarHelper
  include GravatarUtils

  def gravatar_image_tag(user)
    url = gravatar_for(user)
    # ...
  end
end

# app/models/annotation_posted_activity.rb
class AnnotationPostedActivity < NewsfeedActivity
  include GravatarUtils
end
```

Of course, it's probably easier to just use something like [gravatar-ultimate](https://github.com/sinisterchipmunk/gravatar)

Comment: I should note that this is a simple example. If you actually want to go down this route (because for some reason existing gems don't cover what you need to do), then you should check out ActiveSupport::Concern (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) as a useful common idiom for writing modules to be included, and you might want to consider building the functionality as a gem (it keeps your rails codebase nice and clean).